# Fag as a term for donkey work

Tags: meaning

I found in it in some thematic dictionary in "job" chapter, but I'm still reluctant to use it because of the negative meaning it has.

Is it okay to use it? How does it collocates?

Sincerely

Comment: My knee-jerk is to say no but maybe you can at least provide a sample sentence and possibly a link to the original source of that definition?

Comment: You should not use the term IMO. There are more common alternatives. Many words are tainted by association with very offensive words. For example: *niggardly*. This word, like *fag* in its other senses, have been tainted by their association with slurs.

Answer (score 3):

You are right to be reluctant to use the term.

***[Fag](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/fag):***

> - Fag is mainly used as an offensive term for homosexuals. Although it has other meanings, you should probably avoid it at all costs.
> - This is a very strong word that should be avoided in nearly all situations: fag (short for faggot) is a hateful slur against homosexuals. ***Because fag is such an offensive word, the other meanings are uncommon, but fagging has also meant working hard and getting tired, as in fagging out.***  A fag — especially in England — is also a cigarette, and in British boys’ schools, fags are servants for older boys.

(Vocabulary.com)